# form (part1) - content - form (part2)

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm wondering if it's at all possible to do something like this:

```
<form>
some fields here
</form>

<div id=content>
content
</div>

<form=continued>
more fields here
</form>
```

I'm building it in Joomla and so loading 3 modules atm. 
I would like to merge the two forms, without destroying my layout order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. However, this is possible:

```
<form>
some fields here

<div id="content">
content
</div>

</form>
```